# Every irreducible character of $G$ is an irreducible character of $H$?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, characters

Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$ such that for all $\chi\in Irr(G)$, $\chi_H\in Irr(H)$.

That is, the restriction of every irreducible character of $G$ to $H$ is an irreducible character of $H$.

What can be said in that case ? Is there any theorem related to this case ?

Comment: What happens when your subgroup is the identity?

Comment: @draks...: Then $G$ must be abelian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Theorem** Let $G$ be a finite group with a proper subgroup $H$, such that all irreducible characters of $G$ restrict irreducibly to $H$. Then the following hold.
$(a)$ $H$ is a normal subgroup and $G/H$ is abelian
$(b)$ Every irreducible character of $H$ is $G$-invariant
$(c)$ $k(G)=|G:H|k(H)$ (here $k(X)$ denotes the number of conjugacy classes of a group $X$)
$(d)$ $Z(G)=C_G(H)$ and $[G,H]=H'$
$(e)$ If $H$ is a Hall-subgroup, then $H$ is a direct factor of $G$.

**Proof** (a) Since $H$ is proper, $(1_H)^G=1_G+\sum a_{\chi}\chi$, with $a_{\chi}$ positive integers, with at least one $\chi \in Irr(G)$. Assume $\chi \in Irr(G|1_H)$, then by Frobenius Reciprocity, $0 \lt a_{\chi}=[(1_H)^G,\chi]=[1_H,\chi_H]$. Since $\chi_H$ is irreducible we must have $\chi_H=1_H$, so $a_{\chi}=1$, $\chi$ is linear and $H \subseteq ker(\chi)$. Hence, $(1_H)^G$ is the sum of all linear characters $\lambda$ of $G$ with $H \subseteq ker(\lambda)$. This implies that $ker((1_H)^G)=core_G(H)=\bigcap \{ker(\lambda): \lambda_H=1_H\} \supseteq H$. Hence $H=core_G(H)$, that is $H$ is normal and of course $G' \subseteq \bigcap \{ker(\lambda): \lambda_H=1_H\}$, since each $\lambda$ here is linear.
(b) This follows from (a) and Clifford Theory (see for example (6.2)Theorem in Isaacs' CTFG).
(c) We can count the irreducible characters of $H$ and $G$, applying Gallagher's Correspondence Theorem (see (6.17)Corollary in CTFG): let $\chi \in Irr(G)$ and $\chi_H=\vartheta \in Irr(H)$ then $Irr(G|\vartheta)=\{\lambda\chi: \lambda \in Irr(G/H)\}$. Since $G/H$ is abelian, this yields $\#Irr(G)=|G/H|\cdot \#Irr(H)$.
(d) It is easy to prove (using Schur's Lemma) that if $\chi \in Irr(G)$ with $\chi_H \in Irr(H)$, then $C_G(H) \subseteq Z(\chi)$. Since $\bigcap_{\chi \in Irr(G)} Z(\chi)=Z(G)$ and obviously $Z(G) \subseteq C_G(H)$, the assertion follows. For the second statement remember that every linear $\lambda \in Irr(H)$ is $G$-invariant by (b). So for all $g \in G, h \in H$ we have $\lambda(ghg^{-1}h^{-1})=\lambda^g(h)\lambda(h^{-1})=\lambda(h)\lambda(h^{-1})=1$. Hence $[G,H] \subseteq ker(\lambda)$. Since $H'=\bigcap \{ker(\lambda):\lambda \in Irr(H), \lambda(1)=1\}$ and of course $H' \subseteq [G,H]$, we are done.
(e) Assume that $H$ is a Hall-subgroup. Then owing to the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem, $H$ has a complement $A$, with $G=HA$ and $H \cap A=1$. Note that $A$ is abelian. Let $P \in Syl_p(A)$, then by (a) $P$ acts (coprimely) on $H$ by conjugation. By (b) $P$ fixes every element of $Irr(H)$, and hence we can apply Brauer's Permutation Lemma (see (6.32)Theorem in CTFG) and it follows that $P$ fixes every $H$-conjugacy class. Since for every $h \in H$ gcd$(|Cl_H(h)|,p)=1$, $Cl_H(h)$ must contain a fixed point, so an element centralized by $P$. Or otheriwse put $Cl_H(h) \cap C_H(P) \neq \emptyset$. For every conjugacy class $C$ of $H$ pick an $h_C$ fixed by $P$ and put $K=\langle h_C: C \text{ is an } H-\text{conjugacy class} \rangle \leq H$. Then obvioulsy $H=\bigcup_{h \in H}K^h$ and a classical result implies that in fact $H=K$. Hence $H$ is centralized by $P$ and since $A$ is generated by its Sylow-subgroups, it follows that $A$ centralizes $H$, so $G=H \times A$.

**Note** Probably more can be said on the type of group pairs $(G,H)$ above. One thing that is worth mentioning is the "dual" (restriction of characters vs. induction) of the above property. The following was proved by Eric Kuisch (see *Homogeneous Character Induction*, J. Alg. **149**, (1992), 454-471, Theorem(1.2))

**Theorem** Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a proper non-trivial subgroup. Then the following are equivalent.
$(a)$ Each non-trivial irreducible character of $H$ induces irreducibly to $G$
$(b)$ $G$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $H$.

This is quite surprising: $(b) \Rightarrow (a)$ was well-known (see for example (6.24)Theorem in CTFG), but the reverse implication was unknown at that time!

Comment: Happy to see you, after many years Nicky. This was an very old problem of me, even I forgot it. Thank you for your answer. I remember that Isaacs had replied my question, and say something similar to your answer.

Comment: Yes I still had it in my notes and during Christmas I have been working on it. My feeling is that more can be done. Best regards!